# C++ std::vector with pointers to a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

In a project I am working on I am tying to make a vector with pointers to a template class.

```
 template <typename T>
 std::vector<templateClass<T>*> vec;
```

However, this gives me two errors:

```
Error C2133: vec : unknown size
Error C2998: std::vector<templateClass<T>*> vec : cannot be a template definition
```

If I change the code to:

```
std::vector<templateClass<int>*> vec;
```

It works fine, so I guess the problem isn't that you cant use template classes with vectors, but that you need to tell the compiler what type to use. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is this a class member or you try to declare a variable with template?

Comment: You need to provide the context where vec is declared - is it a class member, or a stack object?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just missing a typedef?

Comment: No, the vector isn't part of a class. How would I use a typedef in this situation?

Comment: I don't think typedefs work with templates.

Comment: You really need to provide some context. Would std::vector<T> compile here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want `vec` to contain heterogeneous items (for instance `templateClass<int>*` and `templateClass<float>*`? If so, this is not possible: a vector is an homogeneous container, all its elements must have the same type, and `templateClass<T>` is completely unrelated from `templateClass<U>`. Perhaps you could have a common base class from which `templateClass` instantiations would derive?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a class instance you have to choose the type. In the definition you can write T but at the moment of create instance you have to specify the type.

So if you want define and not creating an instance use `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a templated member.
The template must come from the class or function templated declaration.

```
template <typename T>
class blah {
     std::vector<templateClass<T>*> vec;
}
```

The compiler needs the templated typename to be defined somewhere in the code, for example: `blah<int>`

If you'd have a templated member, you couldn't define the type anywhere in the code, and the compiler wouldn't be able to decide the member's type.

The templated typename is decided when you first use the function or class (either explicitly or implicitly) so you'd have to have the template definition and implementation somewhere that is accessible by the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to define a new type `vec<T>` as a shortcut to the longer templetized expression. Normally, this would be done with a `typedef`, however C++ does not support templetized typedefs.

Note, that in the current code you are essentially trying to define a variable called `vec`, but you are not giving it a specific type for T and that's why the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Currently C++ doesn’t support template typedefs so you have to use the most common solution, proposed by Herb Sutter (http://gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm)

Comment: C++11 has been ratified several months ago, and it includes template typedefs (they are called template aliases). However, [their support](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) is not very widespread in compilers yet.

Comment: That being said, I don't think this is what the OP is looking for. If I understood correctly, I think he wants his vector to contain heterogeneous items: `templateClass<int>*`, `templateClass<float>*`, etc. This is just a guess though.